# Extract comments from text file and append to dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset that takes the form:

```
# prate [mm/day] from 4x Daily NOAA-CIRES 20th Century Reanalysis V2c
# grid point lon,lat =   22.500   63.808
 1851 1.8 0.9 1.7 1.5 1.6 2.7 2.7 2.6 1.3 2.5 1.8 1.7
 1852 2.2 1.6 0.9 1.4 1.6 2.5 2.4 2.0 1.8 2.3 1.9 1.5
...
```

I wish to extract the longitude and latitude from the comments at the top of this text file and add them repeatedly as two additional columns in this dataset. My output should therefore look like so:

```
# prate [mm/day] from 4x Daily NOAA-CIRES 20th Century Reanalysis V2c
# grid point lon,lat =   22.500   63.808
 1851 1.8 0.9 1.7 1.5 1.6 2.7 2.7 2.6 1.3 2.5 1.8 1.7 22.500 63.808
 1852 2.2 1.6 0.9 1.4 1.6 2.5 2.4 2.0 1.8 2.3 1.9 1.5 22.500 63.808
...
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
dat <- read.table('dataset.txt', header = FALSE, skip = 2)
txt <- readLines('dataset.txt', n = 2)

llcols <- read.table(text = trimws(gsub('.*=','',txt[2])), header = FALSE)
names(llcols) <- c('lon','lat')

dat <- cbind(dat, llcols)
```

gives:

```
> dat
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13  lon    lat
1 1851 1.8 0.9 1.7 1.5 1.6 2.7 2.7 2.6 1.3 2.5 1.8 1.7 22.5 63.808
2 1852 2.2 1.6 0.9 1.4 1.6 2.5 2.4 2.0 1.8 2.3 1.9 1.5 22.5 63.808
```

*Explanation:*

- With `dat <- read.table('dataset.txt', header = FALSE, skip = 2)` you read the data and exclude the two comment lines.
- With `txt <- readLines('dataset.txt', n = 2)` you read the two comment lines as text.
- With `trimws(gsub('.*=','',txt[2]))` you extract the lon/lat values.
- And read the result with `read.table` in a new dataframe.
- With `cbind` you combine the two dataframes into one. The lon/lat values will be repeated till the end of `dat`.

---

Reading a bunch of files can be done as follows:

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '.txt')

dflist <- lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  dat <- read.table(x, header = FALSE, skip = 2)
  txt <- readLines(x, n = 2)

  llcols <- read.table(text = trimws(gsub('.*=','',txt[2])), header = FALSE)
  names(llcols) <- c('lon','lat')

  cbind(dat,llcols)
})
```

Comment: Many thanks for this very detailed answer @Jaap. If I wanted to apply this code to multiple identically formatted text files in a folder, how could I amend the code to achieve this? I have been using the lapply function for other code involving lists.

Answer (score 1):

I have now found the solution for applying this to lists as follows:

```
dat=apply(data.frame(list.files()), 1, read.table, header=F, skip=2)
txt=apply(data.frame(list.files()), 1, readLines, n=2)
llcols=lapply(txt, function(x) read.table(text =trimws(gsub('.*=','',txt[2])), header = FALSE))
names(LLCOLS)=c('lon','lat')
dat=lapply(dat, function(x) cbind(x, llcols))
```